# QGIS-3.10 raster calculator crashing on Windows

Tags: osgeo4w, gdal-calc, qgis-3

Trying to add several rasters, all multiplied by certain factors (like `(A@1*.8)+(B@1*.003)+(C@1*.2)...`) in raster calculator in QGIS 3.10 the program crashes on Windows (that doesn't happen on Linux, at least on 3.8, which is what I use mostly); exploring further, GDAL's plugin raster calculator outputs something like "missing module" trying to do the same thing; in Osgeo4w gdal_calc was not listed when I checked the available commands.
 You may just add two rasters on QGIS's calculator without crashing.

Comment: smells like opencl, but i think we would need more information and error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to check the box in "Settings - Options - Acceleration - 'enable acceleration for opencl'". Grass's calculator did work without the setting.gdal_calc was not included in this osgeo4W shell version